# How to disable Ping response (ICMP) in Linux then bring back up?

Tags: linux, ping, icmp

I'm trying to test the aliveness of some of my services by continuously pinging them to make sure they're up. It checks if 'alive' by pinging the address (`192.168.20.1`).

I've tried disabling it via iptables `sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -s 192.168.20.1 -j DROP` but I still get packets transmitted and recieved when I `ping` that IP address.

I've also tried editing the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and adding `net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1` then rebooting via `sysctl -p` to no success. I can simply ping the `192.168.20.1` still and successfully get a response.

Is there any way to block the IP address so that the `ping` command would not successfully return the packets to my host? Also if there's info on bringing it back up that would be appreciated.

**Solution**

Was able to simply block the icmp protocol through this line:

`iptables -A OUTPUT --proto icmp -j DROP`

Since the linux `ping` command works via ICMP simply dropping it for networking would make ping fail. Changing the `-A` to `-D` is how to bring it back up.

Comment: Should you drop the INPUT? Note: the output may be put as "RELATED", and so accepted in a different rule, but we do not know how the rest of your firewall is configured

Comment: 'ping' does not test services , it tests hosts. If you want to test your services then you should be trying to connect to them (i.e. complete a TCP handshake for TCP services / tests for UDP services are protocol specific)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options

```
    sudo echo “1” > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
    sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1 && sysctl -p
    sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp –icmp-type echo-request -j REJECT
    sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp –icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
    sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp –icmp-type echo-reply -j DROP
```

I think your use of `-I` makes sense in `OUTPUT` because as stated by Giacomo, you may have other rules at play before it. Are you sure you install the rule on the correct target machine?

You can list your iptables rules in case none of the above works.

source: https://www.howtouselinux.com/post/disable-ping-in-linux

Comment: ah thank you, Was having an issue with previous rules. For my problem your solution of simply adding a drop to icmp protocol was the solution. Specifically `iptables -A OUTPUT --proto icmp -j DROP` was sufficient for the testing I had to do.